# ¿Quiénes son los moderadores del sitio?

Tags: soporte, moderadores

Hace unos días acabó la elección de nuevos moderadores en Stack Overflow. Como SOes es un sitio nuevo, entiendo que vendrá con moderadores creados por anticipado. ¿Cuándo se realizará la votación o elección de nuevos moderadores? ¿Se tendrá en cuenta su curriculum en SO o en SOes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Esto está explicado en [esta entrada de blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore):

> **¿Cómo se eligen los moderadores temporales?**
>
> Tras alrededor de una semana en la beta pública, **buscaremos a los
>   miembros que están fuertemente involucrados en el desarrollo de la
>   comunidad**; miembros que:
>
> - Tienen una reputación razonablemente alta, lo cual indica participación activa y consistente.
> - Muestran interés en las actividades de construcción de la comunidad en meta.
> - Guían dando ejemplo, mostrando paciencia y respeto por sus compañeros de la comunidad en todo lo que escriben.
> - Muestran los trazos intangibles debatidos en [Una teoría de la moderación](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation).
>
> Puntos extra para:
>
> - Miembros que participan tanto en el sitio meta como en el sitio principal (es decir, tienen interés en la construcción de la comunidad
>     y son expertos en el tema).
> - Participación en Area 51, menciones en redes sociales, o publicaciones sobre el sitio en blogs.
> - Miembros que ya han mostrado interés o habilidad en la promoción de sus propias comunidades.

Comment: Los moderadores serán designados por mi durante nuestro beta público.

Answer (score 4):

Para complementar la [respuesta de Konamiman](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/123/83) sobre cómo se eligen los [moderadores Pro Tempore](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/27/moderator-pro-tempore/), es bueno recordar que la lista de moderadores actuales siempre está disponible en la pestaña *Moderadores* de la [página de Usuarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users):

https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators

Comment: Como dato curioso: ese enlace no funciona en la app, solo en la versión web de esSO