# ¿Con base en qué fundamentos puedo calificar o ser seleccionado como moderador?

Tags: discusión, moderación, elecciones

Entiendo que ser moderador no es una tarea sencilla (al menos es el contexto que imagino) y leyendo en las preguntas de SOMeta veo que los primeros moderadores seleccionaron un tercer moderador así directamente, no mencionan en qué basaron su criterio de selección. Dadas estas incógnitas me surgen varias preguntas.

La primera y la más importante sería:

- **¿Qué requisitos o criterios (zona geográfica, especialidad en ciertas tecnologías, años de experiencia, reputación en otros sitios de SO)  son necesarios para ser moderador?**
- ¿Me puedo postular para ser moderador?
- ¿Cómo fueron seleccionados los primeros dos moderadores?
- ¿En caso de que existan nuevos moderadores cómo sería la selección?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cuando una comunidad de Stack Exchange empieza, los empleados de la empresa seleccionan moderadores Pro Tempore. Esto está descrito muy bien en la entrada del blog [Moderator Pro Tempore](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/). Ahí podemos leer: *Cómo se designan los Moderadores pro témpore*, cuya traducción tenemos en una respuesta de Konamiman a la pregunta [¿Quiénes son los Moderadores del sitio?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/123/83).

Básicamente se eligen entre los miembros más activos de la comunidad que hayan demostrado interés y capacidad para gestionar el día a día de acuerdo con la [Teoría de la Moderación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2227) bajo la que subyace Stack Exchange.

En esa misma publicación el Community Manager del sitio, [Juan M](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m), [indicó](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/121/quienes-son-los-moderadores-del-sitio/123#comment555_123) que:

> Los moderadores serán designados por mi durante nuestro beta público.

Tal y como [vemos en Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish), el sitio sigue en Beta público (hoy cumple 365 días), por lo que entiendo que el proceso de selección seguirá así durante esta fase.

Cuando pase algún tiempo y el sitio se haya consolidado, se graduará. Es decir, ya no será beta público sino... "graduado".

A partir de aquel momento, cuando haya necesidad se convocarán elecciones. El proceso está descrito en [¿Qué es una elección? ¿Cómo se elige y cómo funciona?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2256) Básicamente, se puede presentar todo aquel que tenga las medallas [Convención](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/68/convention), [Ayudante](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/70/deputy), [Strunk & White](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) y [Obligación Civil](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty), así como un mínimo de reputación y no haya sido suspendido en el último año.
Tras una fase de primarias (opcional, pues se salta si no hay demasiados candidatos) se produce una elección final entre los diez finalistas.
Todo aquel que tenga cierta reputación puede votar y allí entran muchas consideraciones: el historial del usuario, de qué zona es (por eso de cubrir franjas horarias), etc.

Cada sitio tiene una página de elecciones en `/election`. Ahora mismo https://es.stackoverflow.com/election indica lo obvio: que no ha habido ninguna.

Como recompensa por el ingente trabajo de esta gente, pueden ganar dos medallas de oro, dependiendo de cuándo y cuánto han estado en el cargo:

> [Alguacil](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/86/sheriff): Servir como moderador electo durante, por lo menos, un año.
>
> [Agente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/85/constable): Servir como moderador pro témpore durante, por lo menos, un año o hasta la graduación del sitio.