# ¿Qué es una elección? ¿Cómo se elige y cómo funciona?

Tags: soporte, faq, elecciones, página-de-elecciones

El cuadro de anuncios muestra que comenzarán las elecciones a moderador.

¿Cómo se elige y cómo puedo participar?

[image: cuadro de anuncios]

---

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

La comunidad está eligiendo a [sus moderadores ♦](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators); a las personas responsables de [moderar el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2227/127).

El proceso de una elección está dividido en 4 etapas.

### Etapa 0: Anuncio y recolección de preguntas

#### Duración: 7 días

La elección se anuncia con una publicación en Meta por parte de un miembro del [Equipo de Comunidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1670/127). En la publicación, se solicitan preguntas que la comunidad quiera hacerle a los candidatos, y así formar el cuestionario de postulación. Las preguntas más votadas pasan a conformar el cuestionario que todo moderador debería responder.

### Etapa 1: Nominación

#### Duración: 7 días

A todos los usuarios en condiciones de votar les llega una notificación que anuncia el inicio de la elección.

A partir de esta etapa, y hasta el final de la elección, todo ocurre en [es.stackoverflow.com/election](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election).

Cualquier persona se puede nominar como moderador, siempre y cuando cumpla un mínimo de condiciones:

- Debe tener un mínimo de reputación (lo cual es una forma de garantizar que los candidatos estén mínimamente familiarizados con el sitio). Por ejemplo, en nuestra primera elección, sólo se presentan candidatos con al menos **300** puntos de reputación.
- Podría haber [un mínimo de medallas requerido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1131/127), que se determina en cada elección.
- No se aceptarán nominaciones de usuarios que [hayan sido suspendidos durante el último año](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274114/304899). La nominación sería eliminada silenciosamente.

Las nominaciones no son definitivas, y los candidatos pueden retractarse en cualquier momento. La lista de candidatos se ordena como una pila, con las nominaciones más antiguas al final de la página.

Cada postulante debe realizar una presentación explicando por qué cree que sería un buen moderador. Cualquier usuario podrá [comentar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) en estas publicaciones, pero esos comentarios no pueden recibir votos ni ser reportados (para contactarte con el equipo de SE sobre cualquier problema, usa la sala de chat creada para la elección).

<kbd>[image: ejemplo ficticio de la postulación de un usuario]</kbd>

Se alienta a que los candidatos respondan el cuestionario de postulación publicado en Meta al inicio de la etapa de nominación.

Obviamente, un usuario no puede postular a otro. Las nominaciones son personales, al igual que cualquier publicación en el sitio.

Después de estos 7 días, los 30 candidatos con mayor reputación avanzan a las *primarias*. En caso de que tengamos menos de 10 candidaturas, que suele ser lo habitual, la elección avanza directo a la 3ª etapa *final*.

### Etapa 2: Primarias

#### Duración: 4 días

Es cuando se inicia la votación. Cualquier miembro de la comunidad con más de **150** de reputación puede votar (un candidato [no se puede votar a sí mismo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170906/304899)). Puedes votar en más de un candidato, tal como en las respuestas en el sitio.

No están habilitados los comentarios.

Se puede votar a favor o en contra de un candidato usando las flechas de votación a la izquierda de la postulación. Un voto a favor indica que te gustaría que ese candidato pase a la próxima etapa. Un voto en contra representa lo opuesto.

<kbd>[image: botones de votación]</kbd>

Los candidatos son listados en orden aleatorio y, al igual que antes, cualquiera puede retractarse abandonando su candidatura si lo quisiera.

El número de votos de cada candidato es público, de modo que se puede tener una noción de quiénes son los candidatos mejor vistos por la comunidad.

Luego de 4 días, los 10 candidatos con más votos pasan la etapa de *elección*.

### Etapa 3: Elección

#### Duración: 4 días (8 días si se omitieron las primarias)

Es la última etapa de la elección y, así como en las primarias, cualquier usuario con más de **150** de reputación puede votar (esta vez los candidatos [pueden votarse a sí mismos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170906/304899)).

No se permiten comentarios, y los candidatos son listados aleatoriamente.

Cada miembro de la comunidad tiene derecho a 3 votos: 1ª, 2ª y 3ª opción para moderador. Puede utilizar cualquier número de votos hasta 3.

<kbd>[image: selección de primera, segunda y tercera opción de candidatos]</kbd>

Esta vez, el número de votos a cada candidato no es público durante la elección, por lo que no se puede ludificar la votación.

Los votos son contabilizados utilizando el [Método Meek de voto único transferible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77541/304899) ([VUT](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voto_%C3%BAnico_transferible)).

### Resultados y otros datos

1. Anuncio de nuestra primera elección en el blog:
   [Ya nos graduamos, ahora ¿qué sigue?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/30/ya-nos-graduamos-ahora-que-sigue/)
2. Las páginas de elecciones previas se preservan para la posteridad y están disponibles en [es.stackoverflow.com/election](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election).

   Durante una elección, esa página no muestra los resultados anteriores, pero éstos siguen disponibles en `/election/<nº de elección>`. Por ejemplo, el resultado de nuestra primera elección estará siempre disponible en [es.stackoverflow.com/election/1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/1).
3. Puedes ver la lista de moderadores actuales en [la página de usuarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) del sitio, o incluso consultar el [listado completo para todos los sitios](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators).

---

> *Adaptado de [There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135360/304899).*

Comment: La página de elecciones publicada ayer no menciona criterios de discriminación como el de no aceptar las de usuarios que han sido suspendidos

Comment: [la página de la elección 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/election/8) dice "...and cannot have been suspended during the past year."

Comment: La página de Meta SE (el enlace al final de la respuesta) también incluye algo similar

Comment: @Rubén tenés razón... Esperaría a que se definen explícitamente, o que terminen de traducirla (si siguen sacando condiciones, pareciera que juegan en contra de la comunidad)

Comment: De acuerdo hay que esperar, pero creo que vale la pena ir identificando dudas actuales y potenciales.

Comment: @Rubén publica las dudas (o después público)

Comment: Empecé por documentar los "problemas" en el chat principal, pero ahí hay mucho ruido, así que cree https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61769/elecciones-2017-soes

Comment: En las primarias, los votos no son del todo públicos. Cuando el balance de votos es negativo, por diseño se muestra -1, aún y cuando sean muchos más los votos negativos. Referencia [mensaje en chat de la elección 2017](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39030967#39030967)

Comment: En cuanto a ver los votos +/-, me parece que al igual que en el sitio principal, se requiere de cierta reputación para poderlos ver (¿+3 000?)