# Elección de moderador de comunidad 2017

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, elecciones, moderadores

¡La elección de moderador de comunidad de 2017 está en marcha!

Las elecciones de moderador de comunidad tienen tres etapas:

1. Etapa de postulación
2. Etapa primaria
3. Etapa de elección

La mayoría de las elecciones llevan entre dos y tres semanas, pero esto depende de la cantidad de candidatos que haya.

Consulta la página de elección oficial en

https://es.stackoverflow.com/election

para obtener más información, ¡y participar!

Si deseas formular preguntas generales sobre el proceso de elección o preguntas para los candidatos a moderador, puedes hacerlo aquí en meta; solo asegúrate de leer la información del proceso en [¿Qué es una elección? ¿Cómo se elige y cómo funciona?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2256/127), y que tus preguntas tengan la etiqueta [elecciones](/questions/tagged/elecciones).