# Traduzcamos las etiquetas election y moderators

Tags: característica-nueva, etiquetas, traducciones, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

El usuario Comunidad ha publicado [Elección de moderador de comunidad 2017](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2479/65) con las etiquetas [election](/questions/tagged/election) y [moderator](/questions/tagged/moderator) podríamos decir que se trata de una etiqueta del sistema, pero seguramente no es una de las predeterminadas, pues aparentemente no existía antes del día de hoy.

Cosa curiosa es que a diferencia de otras etiquetas esta no cuentan, al menos todavía, con un resumen de etiqueta ni con un wiki de etiqueta.

**Relacionado**
[Traduzcamos toda la lista de etiquetas predeterminadas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1887/65).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya he creado los sinónimos. Sin embargo, las etiquetas de la publicación las tuve que cambiar a mano. Quizás es un bug del usuario Comunidad.

> La columna de la izquierda es de etiquetas maestras, mientras que la columna de la derecha son sinónimos.
>
> - [elecciones](/questions/tagged/elecciones)  ← [election](/questions/tagged/election)
> - [moderadores](/questions/tagged/moderadores) ← [moderators](/questions/tagged/moderators)

Comment: Más que del usuario comunidad en sí, debe de ser del proceso usado para realizar la publicación, como no utilizan la UI, se han de "brincar las trancas", por ejemplo, olvidaron disparar la creación del resumen y wiki de etiqueta

Comment: De hecho, "el proceso usado para realizar la publicación" es en verdad el usuario Comunidad :-)