# ¿Habra este año elecciones a nuevos moderadores?

Tags: discusión, moderación, elecciones, moderadores

Mi pregunta surge ya que estamos a dos meses de que se va estar de aniversario del sitio, según leí en meta [Enlace meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99512/when-do-moderator-elections-take-place), los moderadores actuales deciden si va haber o no una elección.
Este es un extracto traducido

> Aunque nos pondremos en contacto con los moderadores en el aniversario de su última elección, solo para ver cómo se desarrollan, las elecciones no siempre tienen lugar al mismo tiempo todos los años. A veces, incluso un año puede pasar sin ninguna elección en absoluto. La mayoría de las elecciones están programadas como resultado de que los moderadores llegan a Stack Exchange para pedir ayuda adicional.

Yo veo que seria algo positivo para el sitio ya que puede motivar algunos usuarios con las características que se necesitan para ser nominados así se trabaje mas en la moderación del mismo ya que actual mente una de las colas de revisión que es la votos de cierre como se muestra en esta imagen.

Con este vemos que si se necesita ayuda que sitio ha crecido lo suficiente.

[image: votos]

Comment: Lo de que son cada año no es así a la práctica: en SO hay veces que se hacen dos en un año, otros uno; también varía el número de plazas que se ofertan.

Comment: Por otra parte, no entiendo los dos párrafos finales: ¿indicas que hay necesidad? ¿qué relación tiene el número de revisiones y quiénes revisaron en la cola de cierre? ¿Podrías clarificarlo? ¡Gracias!

Comment: @ fedorqui Según leí en meta decía que se contactan con los moderadores para ver si se necesita ayuda o no  es así?

Comment: @fedorqui indico la necesidad porque puede ser una motivación para que mas usuarios con esa reputación ayuden o se involucren en la moderación de esta cola de revisión ya que nunca la he visto a cero

Comment: @RaulCacacho el sitio ha crecido continuamente por lo tanto es una buena opción tener más ayuda en las tareas de moderación ¿te deseas a proponer Raul? :-)

Comment: Entiendo. Ahora bien, esto es independiente: la gestión de colas es algo que puede hacer toda la comunidad (a partir de cierta reputación, claro). Los moderadores se encargan de otro tipo de cosas, preferentemente.

Comment: Me parece muy apropiado preguntar si habrá elecciones este año, quizás debería ser algo que se debería preguntar cada año, pero el que pregunta se compromete :P

Comment: Por cierto, aunque se le suele llamar **moderadores** a los **moderadores diamantados** o *supermoderadores*, a partir de 15 puntos de reputación con los que se adquieren los privilegios de votar positivo y reportar publicaciones todos somos moderadores.

Comment: @Elenasys yo no creo que tenga la reputación suficiente para hacerlo, solo hice la pregunta porque me gustaría que hubieran elecciones este año

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sí, tendremos elecciones muy pronto* para añadir a un moderador nuevo para el equipo de SOes. Tenemos necesidad de más ayuda en las tareas de moderación lo cual nos indica que es tiempo de abrir campo para otra persona que quiera postularse.

Las especificas del proceso las compartiremos en los días que vienen.

*Muy pronto quiere decir este mes.

Comment: Probablemente era necesario. Me alegra que se abra de nuevo el proceso.

Comment: donde veo el funcionamiento de este proceso?

Comment: @MiguelZarate en [¿Qué es una elección? ¿Cómo se elige y cómo funciona?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2256/83) se explica todo : )

Comment: Que alegre noticia!!!!

Comment: ¿Será posible que esta vez hayan 5 moderadores?