# ¿Quién son los moderadores ♦? ¿Cuál es su rol?

Tags: soporte, faq, moderadores

> Esta es una traducción semi automática de [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75189/209901). Hay artículos enlazados que están en inglés.

Hay gente en el sitio que tiene un diamante ♦ detrás de su nombre.

- ¿Qué privilegios especiales tienen?
- ¿Cómo puedo convertirme en uno de ellos?
- ¿Quiénes son? ¿Cuántos hay?

Para más información, lee el artículo del Centro de Ayuda [¿Quiénes son los moderadores del sitio, y cuál es su cometido?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)

---

Nota: no debe confundirse a un moderador con ♦ y los empleados de Stack Exchange, como por ejemplo el [Community Team](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1670/83).

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Esta es una traducción de la respuesta aceptada en [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75192/209901)

### ¿Qué privilegios especiales tienen los moderadores diamantados?

Los moderadores de diamantes son manejadores de excepciones humanas. La función principal de [moderadores de diamante](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2227/83) es hacer un seguimiento de [publicaciones reportadas](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/11/raise-a-red-flag/) pero también tienen algunas habilidades especiales necesarias para manejar condiciones excepcionales:

- Tienen acceso a todas las habilidades y privilegios de los usuarios con reputación superior a 25K, independientemente de su reputación<sup>1</sup>.
- Sus votos son vinculantes. En cualquier lugar que requiera un consenso de múltiples usuarios (cierre, reapertura, eliminación, recuperación, revisión, marcado como spam, etc.) un solo voto de moderador alcanzará el umbral y entrará en vigencia de inmediato.
- Pueden migrar preguntas a cualquier sitio en la red de Stack Exchange, no solo a los sitios que los usuarios normales pueden votar. También están exentos de las restricciones de que el sitio de destino debe tener una etiqueta utilizada por la pregunta migrada y no puede tener una pregunta cruzada equivalente.
- Pueden [bloquear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) y desbloquear publicaciones. Las publicaciones bloqueadas no pueden ser votadas, comentadas o modificadas de ninguna manera por los usuarios regulares.
- Pueden redactar revisiones posteriores: esto requiere dos moderadores, uno para realizar la redacción de una revisión y otro para aprobar esta acción.
- Pueden ver más datos en el sistema, incluidas las estadísticas de votos (pero no "quienes votaron por esta publicación") y la información del perfil del usuario.
- Pueden ver todas las publicaciones eliminadas en el perfil de un usuario individual.
- Pueden colocar a los usuarios en suspensión temporal y eliminar a los usuarios si es necesario.
- Pueden realizar acciones de mantenimiento a gran escala, como fusionar preguntas y etiquetas, aprobar sinónimos de etiquetas, migrar preguntas a cualquier sitio sin importar sus etiquetas, etc.
- Pueden convertir una publicación al estado de Wiki de Comunidad y eliminar el estado de cualquier publicación.
- Pueden convertir una respuesta en comentario.
- Pueden editar o eliminar cualquier comentario en cualquier momento y pueden recuperar cualquier comentario no eliminado por el usuario que lo publicó.
- Pueden (a su discreción) liquidar y cancelar una recompensa, que vuelve a calcular el representante del propietario de la recompensa como si nunca la hubiera colocado.
- Pueden eliminar preguntas de sus propios sitios de la lista de Preguntas populares de la red.
- Tienen acceso a un sistema especial que les da acceso prioritario para ponerse en contacto con el equipo de la comunidad de Stack Exchange.
- [No están sujetos a los límites de reportar, votar para cerrar, votar para eliminar, revisión, etc.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189303/180276)
- No pueden ser suspendidos por otros moderadores.

<sup>1</sup> Los moderadores ♦ no pueden votar en las elecciones de moderador sin 150 de reputación. También están sujetos a los requisitos de reputación de más de 2,000 para que no se les solicite hacer comentarios al momento de votar.

### ¿Cómo puedo convertirme en un moderador ♦?

[El conjunto inicial de moderadores temporales](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/27/moderator-pro-tempore/) en los nuevos sitios beta es seleccionado manualmente por el personal de Stack Exchange, generalmente a través de una publicación de nominación en el Meta del sitio.

Ocasionalmente, el personal de Stack Exchange puede hacer llamadas adicionales para moderadores profesionales durante la fase beta. Para los betas de larga duración, el personal puede realizar una elección para permitir que la comunidad vote en futuros nombramientos a plazo.

A medida que estas comunidades crecen, este conjunto inicial es reemplazado por moderadores elegidos. Las elecciones adicionales son convocadas por el personal de Stack Exchange según sea necesario. Puedes leer sobre las elecciones de moderadores aquí: [Cómo funcionan las elecciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2256/83).

En Área 51, no hay moderadores comunitarios, siendo los únicos moderadores el personal de Stack Exchange (ver más abajo). En Meta Stack Exchange, Stack Apps y Ask Patents, los moderadores comunitarios son nombrados por el personal, sin elecciones. (Anteriormente, Meta Stack Exchange fue moderado en su totalidad por el personal de SE, y antes de la separación de Meta Stack Overflow fue moderado por los moderadores de la "Trilogy" - Stack Overflow, Super User y Server Fault-).

### ¿Quiénes son los moderadores diamantados? ¿Cuántos hay?

Cada sitio tiene su propio conjunto de moderadores de diamante, que se enumeran en la página Usuarios (`/users?tab=moderators`) para el sitio correspondiente. En SOes está en https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators. El Meta del sitio comparte los mismos moderadores que sus sitios principales respectivos.

También puedes ver [una lista completa de moderadores de diamante en la red de Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators?by=users) y en qué sitios son moderadores.

Además, los miembros del equipo de Stack Exchange, Inc. tienen la opción de llevar diamantes en cualquier sitio. No están listados en la página de moderadores. Ellos son los únicos moderadores en el Área 51.

Finalmente, el [usuario de la comunidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) en todos los sitios es un perfil de usuario del sistema que se atribuye ciertas acciones automatizadas del sistema. Para obtener más información, consulta [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738)

### ¿Cuánto tiempo dura el término de un moderador?

Si el moderador fue elegido durante una elección que tuvo lugar después de que se graduó el sitio, o fue designado bajo el [proceso especial para nombrar moderadores en Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318630/please-join) en general, conservan el estado de moderador de por vida.

Si el moderador fue designado como moderador "pro-tempore" en un sitio beta, o fue elegido durante una elección mientras el sitio todavía estaba en beta, su estado de moderador finaliza cuando el sitio se gradúa y los nuevos moderadores son elegidos. Para conservar su estado de moderador después de la graduación, deben nominarse a sí mismos como candidatos y ser elegidos.

Si el moderador obtuvo sus privilegios al convertirse en empleado de Stack Exchange, su estado de moderador durará mientras dure su empleo.

Aparte de las reglas anteriores, hay algunos casos en los que se puede quitar el diamante moderador de un usuario. Primero, los moderadores pueden renunciar a su cargo en cualquier momento.

Segundo, se contactará con los moderadores inactivos que no hayan realizado una sola acción durante los últimos seis meses y se les preguntará si desean continuar siendo moderadores. Si no hay respuesta o si responden "no", se eliminarán sus privilegios.

En tercer lugar, hay un [procedimiento para eliminar moderadores](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151606/handling-calls-to-remove-a-moderator) en caso de que las acciones del moderador estén causando problemas con la comunidad. Esto se puede activar por un voto de 2/3 de los moderadores, o por el equipo de SE en respuesta a las aportaciones de la comunidad. Una vez activado, si 2/3 de los otros moderadores que participan en el procedimiento de votación para la eliminación, se revocan los privilegios del moderador.

Finalmente, los privilegios de moderador de los empleados de SE se revocan una vez que finaliza su empleo con SE. Si el empleado era moderador en uno o más sitios en el momento del empleo, sus privilegios pueden ser retenidos en esos sitios cuando finalice su empleo, siempre que aún sean elegibles para tenerlo según los criterios de tenencia anteriores.

Comment: traducción patrocinada por google translate, con revisión rápida por mi parte. Sentíos libres de corregir o mejorar

Comment: @Pablo el asterisco era relevante, porque se explica más abajo que hay matiz. Lo devolví a su sitio.

Comment: Oops!, Vi un /* y pensé en *comentarios en código*, generalmente uso `<sup>` para esas anotaciones. ¿Te parece bien si pongo eso?

Comment: @PabloLozano me parece muy buena idea, gracias!

Comment: @PabloLozano sobre lo de pro tempore, disculpa. No vi ese cambio y por tanto lo revertí sin querer.