# Es recomendado o, "deberías participar" de las Elecciones de Moderador 2021?

Tags: discusión, elecciones

Por casualidad me topé con este post el otro día, dando vueltas en el sitio en inglés.
Obvio, como no participo de este, me abstengo de votar.

Pero ya hoy, me aparece más fuerte que un AD, por lo que ignorarlo ya no puedo.

Dejo el link por si alguien aun no lo ha visto: https://stackoverflow.com/election

En esta publicación, se explica que son los moderadores de la comunidad, que esta pasando (la fase de elecciones) y que se espera de ellos. Seguido continua un listado de personas, que al parecer, son las mismas que el sitio en inglés, entonces pensé.

Realmente, estas elecciones no influyen directamente, se vee gente destacable, pero que jamás podría tener una directa interacción con ellos, por lo que me cuestiono el si, mi participación, siendo relativamente nuevo en el sitio, es necesaria o no.

Mismo caso, preguntar si existen elecciones más específicas para el sitio en español, en donde uno encuentre nombres más conocidos, o al menos personas que hablen regularmente el español y terminen siendo participes del sitio SOes.

Comment: Si no haces uso del sitio en inglés, no le veo sentido, pero si lo usas yo si recomendaría participar. En cuanto a [es.so], [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election) tienes las elecciones que hemos tenido en el sitio

Comment: Desde 2019 entonces no se han realizado nuevas elecciones ni revisiones a los moderadores ??

Comment: No existen "revisiones" a los moderadores. En cuanto a elecciones, solo se realizan cuando es necesario para el sitio. [Aqui](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2256/15301) tienes todo explicado

Comment: Entonces que sucede con los moderadores que han dejado de ser activos ?? Por que, miré al listado que pasaste, y solo desconozco 1 nombre, el cual al revisar su perfil, tampoco tiene actividad hace un buen par de meses.

Comment: Solo ha habido un caso de un moderador que renunció a su cargo. Ya no es moderador, por voluntad propia. Quitando eso, el cargo de moderador es "de por vida", no hay limite temporal

Comment: Comprendo, también desconocía de eso. Muchas gracias.

Comment: voya nominar a @Excorpion para MOD... XD

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent wait what ?? no XD