# Los moderadores deben ser imparciales. Y parecerlo

Tags: discusión, moderación

Como dice [A Theory of Moderation - Una Teoría sobre Moderación](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) de Jeff Atwood:

> Your goal is to guide the community with gentle -- but firm --
> intervention. Respect your fellow community members at all times;
> demonstrate fairness and impartiality in your actions.
>
> Tu objetivo es guiar a la comunidad con una intervención suave pero
> firme. Respeta a tus compañeros miembros de la comunidad; demuéstrales
> ecuanimidad e imparcialidad en tus acciones.

Pero hay una notable falta de imparcialidad.

Un moderador no debiera de moderar un tema en el que participa.
Entiendo que al haber pocos moderadores si se encuentra un tema que requiere
moderación no puede acudir a otro moderador. Pero lo que sí puede hacer es
dejar de participar en el tema a partir del momento en que ha decidido actuar
de moderador; y no ha sido el caso.

Esto ya sucedió al menos una vez en septiembre del año pasado. Preferí tratarlo privadamente en aquella ocasión para no menoscabar la moderación en el sitio. Acaba de volver a suceder. No se puede permitir que esto siga pasando.

### Septiembre de 2016

Mendoza actúa en calidad de moderador en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/22385/301). Borra algunos comentarios y mueve otros a [un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44868/discussion-on-answer-by-jose-antonio-dura-olmos-programacion-de-juegos-2d-de-baj) en [este punto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22357/programaci%C3%B3n-de-juegos-2d-de-bajo-nivel-c-lua-que-escoger/22385#comment35977_22385). El mismo Mendoza reconoce un error :

> @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos he recuperado el comentario que colocaste. Lo
> borré por error desde el celular. Mis más sinceras disculpas.

Pero lo grave no es eso. Lo grave es que después de actuar como moderador en los comentarios de esa respuesta también actúa como parte: [1](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32091585#32091585), [2](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32097014#32097014), [3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22357/programaci%C3%B3n-de-juegos-2d-de-bajo-nivel-c-lua-que-escoger/22385#comment35984_22385) y [4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22357/programaci%C3%B3n-de-juegos-2d-de-bajo-nivel-c-lua-que-escoger/22385#comment35985_22385). Los dos últimos como comentarios fuera del chat.
El señor Mendoza se atreve a juzgar que algunos de sus propios comentarios no constituyen discusión extendida a la vez que juzga que otros comentarios propios y ajenos sí constituyen discusión extendida. Esto es inaceptable incluso aunque hubiese acertado. **No se puede moderar a si mismo**.

### Febrero de 2017

En [esta respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1348/301) se produce el siguiente intercambio de comentarios:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Después un moderador, probablemente Mendoza, borra los comentarios rodeados por un rectángulo rojo en la captura anterior. Y después Mendoza pone el mismo varios comentarios.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**SEIS COMENTARIOS**, seis pone Mendoza. Y después pasa todos los comentarios indiscriminadamente a [un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53003/discussion-on-answer-by-jose-antonio-dura-olmos-es-legitimo-pedir-reputaciones). ¿Es ese tu ejemplo de cómo no usar los comentarios para conversaciones extendidas, Mendoza?
Como mínimo el primer comentario, el de sstan, no merecía ser movido. No estoy de acuerdo con sstan pero debo defender y agradecer su correcta intervención, sstan no es culpable en absoluto de haber utilizado los comentarios para una conversación extendida. Su comentario era relevante y proponía una mejora para la respuesta, que es exáctamente para lo que son los comentarios.

Pero, como ya he dicho anteriormente, lo peor no es que Mendoza modere mal, lo peor es que no es imparcial, participa en aquello que el mismo modera, con lo que **Mendoza se modera a si mismo.**

Comment: Eso es complicado, tampoco debe ser la idea de que los moderadores ya no pueden opinar para ser capaz de moderar. Obviamente se requiere una mano fina en moderar una conversación en que uno mismo participa, y sería mejor de tener alguien más para eso. También hay que tener en cuenta que los moderadores son usuarios cualquieras con un poco más responsabilidades y los privilegios que se juntan a eso, no personal pagado.

Comment: Si te refieres a [esta publicación tuya en particular](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1348/227), se ha explicado bastante en los comentarios e incluso se ha movido a un chat para que cualquier persona pueda comentar. En la [sala de chat creada](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53003/discussion-on-answer-by-jose-antonio-dura-olmos-es-legitimo-pedir-reputaciones) no has vuelto a responder, lo cual deja más dudas que respuestas de tu parte.

Comment: Además de ello, coincido con @sstan, provee ejemplos en tu publicación mediante publicaciones y comentarios donde el moderador (Miquel o yo) se muestra parcial frente a la situación. Con un par de ejemplos es suficiente.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza no tengo la más minima intención de comentar tu actuación como moderador en [ese chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53003/discussion-on-answer-by-jose-antonio-dura-olmos-es-legitimo-pedir-reputaciones). Ese chat y esa respuesta son respecto a la pregunta "¿Es legítimo pedir reputaciones?" y a ese tema deben limitarse y no a hablar sobre tu actuación como moderador.

Comment: @StefanNolde en efecto, los moderadores siguen siendo usuarios. Y me parece muy bien que participen y opinen en el sitio. Pero no que a la vez participen y moderen en la misma cuestión. Y desde luego me parece del todo inaceptable que un moderador se modere a si mismo, como hace Mendoza.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos gracias para confirmar lo que dije, pero viendo como editaste tu publicación te recomiendo de tomar un respiro y hacerte la pregunta: en un sitio con 20000+ usuarios y dos moderadores, que esperas que un moderador hubiera hecho? Y que reacción respetuosa esperas si faltas el respeto a una persona? Hay critica? Si, yo también lo tengo, pero aplica un poco más criterio.

Comment: Dices "no tengo la más mínima intención de comentar tu actuación como moderador en ese chat" pero es justo lo que acabas de hacer...

Comment: Mendoza, es evidente que uso esa frase en el mismo sentido que "Tu actitud como moderador no la voy a comentar en ese chat" y no en el sentido "Tu actitud como moderador en ese chat no la voy a comentar". Lo hace evidente el que después diga que ese no es el tema del chat, motivo por el que no trato ese tema en ese chat. No debieras animar a los usuarios a hablar fuera de tema, Mendoza. @StefanNolde No espero que actúe, su trabajo es voluntario. Pero si actúa debe ser con imparcialidad. ¿Tu crees que ha sido imparcial en los dos casos que he puesto?

Comment: Transferió un chat en comentarios a donde pertenece - a un chat. Hubiera hecho lo mismo. No por mañas, no por ego, solamente por que alguien tuvo que hacerlo. Y eso empieza quedar un debate circular. Si quieres un moderador imparcial, dale espacio para serlo y no lo provoques. Así eso es tirando la piedra y esconder la mano. No lo compro, y eso para mi cierra este tema, porque empieza parecer trolléo.

Comment: @StefanNolde Si tu lo hubieses hecho no habría queja de parcialidad, pues tu no participaste del chat. Mendoza sí participó en el chat. Supongamos que en efecto eso es lo que había que hacer, que mover todos los comentarios del segundo caso a un chat incluyendo el de sstan, es lo correcto; ¿es esta una actuación imparcial por parte de Mendoza?

Answer (score 6):

Un moderador tiene que ser imparcial en **ejecutar los privilegios que únicamente un moderador tiene**, y en la **explicación que da directamente** en el contexto de esta acción, como borrar una publicación, expulsar un usuario etc.

Aparte de eso un moderador es un usuario como todos los demás y recomiendo en el interés de la paz mundial a todos de verlo así. Yo no hablo distinto a un moderador que a otro usuario y no espero un tratamiento distinto **de** un moderador en conversaciones. Simplemente espero de un moderador que no abusa sus privilegios, y de eso no veo nada en el contexto.

Recién tuve una discusión con Luiggi sobre la interpretación hasta que nivel se tiene que poner cuadrado en eliminar todas las cortesías de las contribuciones. El me editó mi publicación, borrándome exactamente las cortesías que yo traté de usar para dar un ejemplo. Un abuso de sus privilegios? **No**, cualquier usuario con 1500+ reputación podría haberlo hecho sin revisión de pares. Yo tuve la opción de ponerlos de nuevo. No lo hice, porque también me divertí con la ironía del asunto.

El tema hubiera cambiado si yo por ejemplo hubiera repuesto lo que fue editado y como resultado hubiera pasado una intervención con privilegios de moderación para forzar el asunto, pero de eso no he visto **nada** todavía de Luiggi.

Quizás así se puede entender porque en este sistema de edición comunitaria la imparcialidad de los moderadores solamente toca los privilegios que los demás no tienen. Y eso también esta explicado en el texto que citaste.

*"Yo no estoy de acuerdo con lo que usted dice, pero me dejaría matar para que usted pudiera decirlo"* - Voltaire

(que nadie se atreve de editarme el Voltaire, no es una signatura, tiene su sentido aqui. Si no lo entienden - *omitir*)

Comment: buena respuesta pero *nota*: es mas de 1000 de rep para editar automaticamente (estando en fase beta)

Comment: Absolutamente de acuerdo. Desde aquí mi agradecimiento público a Luiggi (y también a Miquel) por el trabajo que están desempeñando, tanto en este caso particular como en general.

Answer (score 2):

## Respuesta corta

Si bien la crítica constructiva es muy útil, lo que más necesitamos en este momento es incrementar el porcentaje de preguntas respondidas así como el número de publicaciones diarias.

## Explicación

Entre ayer y hoy que me he dado tiempo de estar explorando Meta me topado con varios hilos quejandose del moderador designado por "dedazo".

En mi opinión, la "mejor solución" es enfocarnos en lograr graduar SOes de tal forma que tengamos "derecho" a eligir a nuestros moderadores "democráticamente"

## Nota al margen

Dios nos libre de un moderador populista

Repitan después de mí, ¡Amén!

## Referencias

- [¿Para cuando unas elecciones para tener un moderador moderado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/800/para-cuando-unas-elecciones-para-tener-un-moderador-moderado)
- [Objetivos del 2017 - Primera Parte (1)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1275/objetivos-del-2017-primera-parte-1)
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish

## Anexos

### Publicaciones relacionadas

- [¿Con base en qué fundamentos puedo calificar o ser seleccionado como moderador?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1129/con-base-en-qu%C3%A9-fundamentos-puedo-calificar-o-ser-seleccionado-como-moderador)
- [¿Quiénes son los moderadores del sitio?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/121/qui%C3%A9nes-son-los-moderadores-del-sitio)

### Captura de pantalla

Página de SOes en español en Area 15 donde se publica el estado del sitio

[image: 4 de febrero de 2017 9:09 PM Tiempo del Centro de México (UTC-6)]